# The variance of $\left(\frac{kX}{1+kX}\right)$ when $X$ is lognormal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I was wondering if $X$ is lognormal, and $k$ is "small enough", can we conclude that $var\left(\frac{kX}{1+kX}\right)$ is negligible? Notice that

$$var\left(\frac{kX}{1+kX}\right)=k^2var\left(\frac{X}{1+kX}\right).$$

I guess this would depend if it's reasonable to assume that $var\left(\frac{X}{1+kX}\right)$ is bounded or does not go wild when $k\to 0.$ Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking if $$\lim_{k \to 0^+} \mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{kX}{1+kX} \right) = 0 $$ then this is true. To see this, observe that for $k > 0$, $$\mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{X}{1+kX} \right) = \inf_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}\left[\left( \frac{X}{1+kX} - c \right)^2\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\left( \frac{X}{1+kX} \right)^2\right] \leq E(X^2) < \infty$$
Hence, it follows that $$\mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{kX}{1+kX} \right) = k^2 \mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{X}{1+kX} \right) \to 0$$

Comment: Will the same hold if $X$ is normal?

Comment: @Heisenberg This argument won't hold as the second-to-last inequality assumed $X \geq 0$. You may be able to prove it for normal $X$ by a direct computation. Intuitively, it should hold, as $kX$ concentrates at zero and $1+kX$ concentrates at $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Second moment is explicitly $\frac{k^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x}{(1+kx)^2}e^{-\frac{(lnx-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx\to 0$, as $k\to 0$.  Therefore variance $\to 0$.

Comment: Will the same hold if $X$ is normal?

Comment: If $X$ is normal, it can be negative so $1+kX$ can be $0$, possibly leading to infinities for mean and variance.  It needs to be checked.